# What is the optimal way to organise data product - and its history prices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have some issue to solve, hope you will help me. I'd like to store history of price change. I've model products (every time I buy something I add it into my warehouse - name, price, quantity or so on) also I want to get last added price - how can I solve it in the proper way? To have last price, history of changed prices and to be DRY. So ie:

warehouse has_many products (with quantity)

product has_many prices

also I have meal recipes where I'd like to know actual food cost (using last added price) and I'd like to have history, that given meal or product cost me $30 few month ago and today it cost me $40...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to have multiple dimensions for this. I would recommend one table for the products current status that is updated each time the price changes to the most recent price. This same update would create a new row in another table that just stores changes made to the price and a third table for the meal information. This would store the data needed but you would still need to do some querying to join the tables in order to get the meal information

```
PRODUCT_TABLE (one line for each product)
  PROD_ID (primary key)
  PROD_INVENTORY_QUANTITY
  PROD_PRICE_CURRENT  
  PROD_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP

PRICE_CHANGE_TABLE (many to one relationship to PRODUCT_TABLE)
  CHNG_ID
  CHNG_DATE
  CHNG_PRICE_FROM
  CHNG_PRICE_TO
  PROD_ID (foreign key)

MEAL_TABLE  (one to many relationship with PRODUCT_TABLE)
  MEAL_ID
  PROD_ID (foreign key)
  PROD_QUANTITY_NEEDED (amount needed for meal would be multiplied by current price for the current cost and joined to the change table with with a date to get past price then summed up with a group by for the meal total)
```